# Possible bug in Spring HttpHeaders

Tags: spring

I found what I believe could be a bug in the Spring classes `HttpHeaders` and `ReadOnlyHttpHeaders`. I want to confirm this before raising a Jira defect with Spring. Here is a snippet of the code I use to create an empty `HttpHeaders` object:

```
HttpHeaders myHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY);
```

I then add headers to my new object using:

```
myHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip")
```

After this `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` is not empty anymore

```
HttpHeaders.EMPTY.size() == 1
```

The javadoc for HttpHeaders.EMPTY states:

> /**
>        * The empty {@code HttpHeaders} instance (immutable).
>        */
>       public static final HttpHeaders EMPTY

The problem here is that when 'HttpHeaders.EMPTY' is used elsewhere, it introduces unexpected headers.

Consider the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateEmptyHeaders() {
    assertEquals(0, HttpHeaders.EMPTY.size()); // **Success**
    HttpHeaders myHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY);
    myHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    assertEquals(0, HttpHeaders.EMPTY.size()); // **Assert Fails**
}

@Test
// This test will fail if run after the test above, but will be successful if run by itself
public void testEmptyHeaders() {
    assertEquals(0, HttpHeaders.EMPTY.size()); 
}
```

Here is the result of the unit tests:

```
// testUpdateEmptyHeaders
08:39:28.450 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@2e222612, testMethod = testUpdateEmptyHeaders@AuditContextTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<1>

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :1

// testEmptyHeaders
08:39:28.482 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@2e222612, testMethod = testEmptyHeaders@AuditContextTest, testException = java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<0> but was:<1>

java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :0
Actual   :1
```

I feel that this is a bug since `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` should be immutable.
I have also been able to fix this by making two changes in Spring `HttpHeaders.java` and `ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reported this bug and it is fixed in Spring 5.1.4 as per https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17633

Answer (score 2):

Yup you are right this might be bug for spring framework `HttpHeaders`

```
public static final HttpHeaders EMPTY
```

> > HttpHeaders.EMPTY This will return empty HttpHeaders instance (immutable). (and it is singleton)

**Case :1**
Let's take a look at `HttpHeaders.Empty`, which returns immutable object

```
    HttpHeaders head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));  //1338668845
    
    System.out.println(head.size());                    //0
    
    HttpHeaders myHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY); 
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(myHeaders));  //159413332
    
    myHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); 
    
    head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY; 
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));       //1338668845
    System.out.println(head.size());                    //1
    System.out.println(head);                            //{Accept-Encoding=[gzip]}
    
    HttpHeaders head1 = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
    System.out.println(head1);                          //{Accept-Encoding=[gzip]}
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head1));   //1338668845
```

**Conclusions :**

> 1 : `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` is always returning the singleton object
>
> 2: The problem is when `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` is passed to `writableHttpHeaders` method internally the returned object is having relation with  `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` singleton object, look at case 2

**Case :2** return object from`writableHttpHeaders` reflects to `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` singleton object (internally and indirectly)

```
    HttpHeaders head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;           
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));  //1338668845
    
    System.out.println(head.size());                //0
    
    HttpHeaders myHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY); 
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(myHeaders));  //159413332
    
    myHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); 
    
    myHeaders.add("hello", "value");
    
    head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY; 
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));  //1338668845
    System.out.println(head.size());              //2
    System.out.println(head);                     //{Accept-Encoding=[gzip], hello=[value]}
    
    HttpHeaders head1 = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
    System.out.println(head1);                    //{Accept-Encoding=[gzip], hello=[value]}
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head1));   //1338668845
    
    myHeaders.remove("hello");
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));     //1338668845
    System.out.println(head.size());                 //1
    System.out.println(head);                       //{Accept-Encoding=[gzip]}
    
    System.out.println(head1);                        //{Accept-Encoding=[gzip]}
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head1));    //1338668845
```

**Conclusion :**

> 1 : `add` and `remove` operations performed on `myHeaders` object are reflecting to `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` object

**Case : 3** Suppose if we pass empty instance of the HttpHeaders object to `writableHttpHeaders` using constructor then there is no issue everything works pretty clear

```
    HttpHeaders head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));       //1338668845
    
    System.out.println(head.size());                     //0
    
    HttpHeaders myHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(new HttpHeaders()); 
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(myHeaders));       //1323165413
    
    myHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); 
    
    myHeaders.add("hello", "value");
    
    head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY; 
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));           //1338668845
    System.out.println(head.size());                    //0
    System.out.println(head);                           //{}
    
    HttpHeaders head1 = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
    System.out.println(head1);                           //{}
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head1));   //1338668845
```

**Case : 4** Even though indirectly immutable `HttPHeaders.EMPTY` can be modified, but still it throws an error if you try modifying directly

```
    HttpHeaders head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));
    
    System.out.println(head.size());
    
    HttpHeaders myHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY); 
    
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(myHeaders));
    
    myHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); 
    
    head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY; 
    System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(head));
    System.out.println(head.size());
    System.out.println(head);
    
    head.add("hello", "value");
```

**Output :**

```
1338668845
0
159413332
1338668845
1
{Accept-Encoding=[gzip]}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at org.springframework.http.ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.add(ReadOnlyHttpHeaders.java:67)
at com.demo.NestedJsonParse.main(NestedJsonParse.java:40)
```

**Final Conclusion :** Yes it is bug you can raise a bug for spring projects [spring-bug](https://jira.spring.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa), immutable objects cannot change the state

Comment: Thank you for your comment @deadpool, but I think you misunderstood the question. As you rightly said, when you use the immutable `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` as input to  `HttpHeaders.writableHeaders()` you get a mutable object you can add headers to. The problem is that any further calls to the immutable `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` does not return an empty HttpHeaders, but contains the header added to the mutable object.

As an example example, the following unit test would fail if it is run after the unit test where headers were added to the mutable object

Comment: Sorry i did not get your point, can you please explain more with details or update in the post? Just bold the point @athom

Comment: I have added a second unit test in the example above which fails when run after the first unit test to show the underlying value of `HttpHeaders.EMPTY` is changed

Comment: i don't think so, i tried with loop, always got `0` and empty map `{}` @athom

Comment: Please also note the first and last asserts in the unit test testEmptyHeaders() gets the value of HttpHeaders.EMPTY and should be empty in both cases

Comment: Can you add sysout statements in both testcases and paste the result here for failure once @athom

Comment: Your test case 2 is not valid. Do the following:
   HttpHeaders head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
   System.out.println(head.size());
   HttpHeaders myHeaders = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY);
    myHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
    head = HttpHeaders.EMPTY;
   System.out.println(head.size());